# How do i code this usin while loop and Python

Tags: python

> Create a program that multiplies all the numbers from 1,2,3, ... and ends when the product is greater than 1000.

I tried this code but it does not work.

```
produkt = 1
while produkt<1000:
    print(produkt)
    produkt = produkt*(produkt +1)
    if produkt < 1000:
        break
```

Comment: "greater than 1000", then why are you breaking when `< 1000`?

Comment: Use different variables for the result and the current loop iteration.  And remove the `break`.

Comment: it should work even without  `if ... :break` - eventually you would need `while ... <= 1000:` But if you need `break` on then you need `if ...> 1000` instead of `if ... < 1000` because `greater` means `>`

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 variables, one to store the `total` and one to store the `index` (1, 2, 3, ...)

```
index = 1
total = 1
while index < 1000:
    total *= index  # same as: total    = total * index
    index += 1  # same as: index = index +1
    # print(f'{index - 1} => {total}') uncomment if you want to follow the values

print(f"Stop at total {total}, index was {index}")
```

You'll get the following

```
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 6
4 => 24
5 => 120
6 => 720
7 => 5040
8 => 40320
9 => 362880
10 => 3628800
...
Stop at total 402...000, index was 1000
```

Comment: I'd rename the variables while you are at it. `produkt` isn't actually a product anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
number = 1
produkt = number
while produkt<=1000:
    print(produkt)
    number += 1
    produkt = produkt * number
```

Result:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
```

Answer (score 0):

```
produkt = 1
counter = 2
while produkt < 1000:
    print(produkt, end=" ")
    produkt = produkt * counter
    counter += 1
print(produkt)
```

1 2 6 24 120 720 5040

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code in the following way: variable `produkt` takes values 1,2,3,... and their product is stored in `produkt_end`.

```
produkt = 1
produkt_end = 1
while True:
    print(produkt_end)
    produkt_end = produkt_end*produkt
    produkt = produkt+1
    if produkt_end > 1000:
        break
```

It will show `produkt_end`:

```
1
1
2
6
24
120
720
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.

```
>>> next(filter(1000 .__lt__, itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1), operator.mul)))
5040
```